Finding a call stack programmatically (unwind?) on nRF82540/ARM/IAR/FreeRTOS
I am attempting to write a routine that monitors the heap in order to track down a memory leak.  I've seen similar tools on other platforms and found them quite helpful.  To make this even more effective, I want to record the caller to malloc() that made the request. To do this, the routine would need to read the call stack (sometimes called unwind).  I've been googling and found clues for the GNU compiler, and other platforms but nothing that seems pertinent to my platform: nRF52840/ARM/IAR/FreeRTOS.
I realize this is extremely unportable, but this is only needed for debugging on occasion.
Anyone have any suggestions?  I've seen references to unwind.h, but they appear to only be for GNU.

There is no way to do this out of the box. The layout and size of the call frame is not explicitly available anywhere on the target. It may be possible to write a tool that analyzes the debug info and builds unwind tables that can be linked into the application but there is nothing available out of the box.

Perhaps you are after IAR's C-RUN runtime heap analysis. It automatically instruments the code so that preventable leaks can be detected on the fly.
It is available as an add-on though there is a trial version as well.
https://github.com/iarsystems/crun-evaluation-guide?tab=readme-ov-file#heap-checking-capabilities

That does sound like it might help in this one case, but the stack unwind capability is useful in many other areas, and can be deployed into the end-user scope for postmortem analysis.  I'll check to see if anyone in my company is using it.  The menu on my IDE has it greyed out, so I might need to do some more digging.

The heap monitoring features in their runtime analyzer comes pre-installed as a built-in add-on. However, in most cases, it is required to reach out to IAR in order to activate the feature in the associated license once the evaluation period expires. The instrumentation also provides backtrace information for tracking down the culprit. Hope it helps!
